Может ли Google заблокировать почту, с которой программа шлёт коды подтверждения пользователям?
У меня есть сервер, который должен слать коды подтверждения, например, через Gmail. Может ли случится так, что из-за большого количества писем гугл снесёт почтовый ящик и все перестанет работать?

Механизм кодов подтверждения часто используют спамеры чтоб завалить ящик письмами. Если через вас начнут кого-то заваливать и он пожалуется - вас заблокируют.
Просто рассылать письма можно. Лимиты по рассылке вам никто не скажет, но не стоит отправлять 1000 писем в один момент.
